# Linked text to change screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to highlight the “Create account ” text in the attached image so I used “TapGestureRecognizer” . However, I cant find a way to change screen upon tap of “Create Account”.  Please can someone tell me how to use “TapGestureRecognizer”  to change screens, or any other preferred solution I can use in achieving the same goal.

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFd8w.png)

```
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
  child: RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
              text: ‘I do not have an account’,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)
          ),
          TextSpan(
              text: ' Create account’,
              style: new TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(24, 44, 228, 1)),
              recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer(
              )
          ),
        ]
    ),
  ),
)

class CreateAccount extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create account'),
      ),
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested below code in dartpad.dev and it works well.
Would you check other code or let me know structure?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
              text: 'I do not have an account',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87)
          ),
          TextSpan(
              text: ' Create account',
              style: new TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(24, 44, 228, 1)),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CreateAccount()),
              );
            }
          ),
        ]
    ),
    );
  }
}



class CreateAccount extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create account'),
      ),
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and there were no errors, but the screen did not change onTap

Comment: @IfeoluwaWole-Osho I tested whole test code I updated. I confirmed page changing is occured.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the TextSpan widget with InkWell widget instead of using  TapGestureRecognizer and in onTap method, you can write your code to navigate to the other screen.

```
        InkWell(
          child: TextSpan(...),
          onTap: () {
            // Your logic here
          },
        )
```